# OnResume() is not called in TabHost in Android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, onresume

I am working with Tabs in my application. Worked on the TabHost Class to make it customize.

When I have **PARENT --> CHILD** activity, in this case on **back press**, **onResume** of Parent Activity is not called in my application.

I am using the below code:

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

    private ArrayList<String> mIdList;
    private HashMap<String, Window> mWindowStorage = new HashMap<String, Window>();//UPDATED
    private boolean _isFromResume;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * This is called when a child activity of this one calls its finish method. 
     * This implementation calls {@link LocalActivityManager#destroyActivity} on the child activity
     * and starts the previous activity.
     * If the last child activity just called finish(),this activity (the parent),
     * calls finish to finish the entire group.
     */
    @Override
    public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
        LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
        int index = mIdList.size()-1;

        if (index < 1) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        String actName = mIdList.get(index);
        manager.destroyActivity(actName, true);
        mWindowStorage.remove(actName);
        mIdList.remove(index); index--;
        String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
        Window newWindow = null;
        if(mWindowStorage.containsKey(lastId)){
            newWindow = mWindowStorage.get(lastId);
        }else{
            Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
            newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
        }
        setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());  
    }

    /**
     * Starts an Activity as a child Activity to this.
     * @param Id Unique identifier of the activity to be started.
     * @param intent The Intent describing the activity to be started.
     * @throws android.content.ActivityNotFoundException.
     */
    public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
        Window window = null;
        if(mWindowStorage.containsKey(Id)){
            window = mWindowStorage.get(Id);
            if(_isFromResume){
                setFromResume(false);
                mIdList.clear();
                mIdList.add(Id);
                mWindowStorage.clear();
                mWindowStorage.put(Id, window);
            }
        }else{
            window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));   
            if (window != null) {
                mIdList.add(Id);
                mWindowStorage.put(Id, window);
            }
        }
        setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
    }

    /**
     * The primary purpose is to prevent systems before android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
     * from calling their default KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK during onKeyDown.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    /**
     * Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
     * so that all systems call onBackPressed().
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    /**
     * If a Child Activity handles KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
     * Simply override and add this method.
     */
    @Override
    public void  onBackPressed  () {
        int length = mIdList.size();
        if ( length > 0) {
            Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
            current.finish();
        }  
    }

    public void setFromResume(boolean isFromResume) {
        _isFromResume = isFromResume;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
        RegisterDeRegisterResponse register = RegisterDeRegisterResponse
                .getInstance();
        register.notifyRegisteredUser(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        register.deRegisterForServerResponse((IResultResponse) activity);
    }
    public void switchTab(int i) {
        WeddingTabActivity parentActivity = (WeddingTabActivity) getParent();
        parentActivity.switchTab(i);
    }
}
```

Also worked with default **startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) and finishFromChild(Activity child)** methods but in that case every Activity is relaunched on BackPress.

```
     @Override
      public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
          LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
          int index = mIdList.size()-1;

          if (index < 1) {
              finish();
              return;
          }

          manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
          mIdList.remove(index); index--;
          String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
          Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
          Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
          setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
      }

 public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
 Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
      if (window != null) {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }    
  }
```

Comment: dont't use tabhost,i used in one of project and finally end up with pulling my hair off.

Comment: what are you saying.... :( I have to do this in any manner....

Comment: i am just saying that instead of tabhost use actionbar,its very easy.

Comment: Already done with 80% of the work.........

Answer (score -1):

In tab host I have done a whole project and then same problem I have the onresume does not get called.. and the activity group is now deprecated and you will be not able to call onresume check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378867/call-onrestart-onresume-when-click-on-back-button) may be it will help.. best of luck